# how to do partition in linux

Tags: debian, ubuntu, partition

I got 500GB disk I had installed windows10 and divided partition:
Local C: 100GB,Local D: 200G,Local E: 200GB
Now I am doing clean instal of Linux system on this disk and I would like to have same partition as above.
I used 100GB for creating root,swap and home partition now I would like to use rest of the storage space(200GB+200GB) into two different local disk just like I had in windows

Comment: Those are NTFS partitions? Manually Mount NTFS
https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072 Do not try to use permissions as one answer suggests.  This show a typical fstab entry: https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions

Comment: It's no clear. Do you want to keep existing data on those two drives ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing GParted (https://gparted.org/).

It's a complex piece of software but it will let you customize your hard drives as you like.
Please, don't forget to read the documentation and be sure of what you are doing before applying changes to your system.

Here is a list of most commands to install it on linux systems:
Debian `sudo apt-get install gparted`
Fedora `su -c "yum install gparted"`
OpenSUSE `sudo zypper install gparted`
Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install gparted`
Linux Mint `sudo apt install gparted`